# Converting multiple CSVs to shapefiles?

Tags: arcpy, python, convert, csv

I have a script that I've used to import information in a CSV to a shapefile.

What I'd like to do is make it so that this script will run on all CSVs in a specific folder location, creating multiple shapefiles.

This is a bit beyond my current programming skills. Can someone point me in the right direction? The current script that imports from a single CSV is below.

```
import arcpy
import csv
import os
print "arcpy imported"

"""
# Author: John K. Tran
# Contact: jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu

Input CSV can look like:

Lat,Lon,First Name,Last Name
12.34,56.78,Joe,Smith
0.98,7.65,Jane,Doe
65.43,43.21,Bob,Sagat

Make sure 'Lat' and 'Lon' fields are the 1st and 2nd column in the CSV 
respectively.

"""


incsv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Change this to the path of your CSV file.
outfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + "\\" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) + ".shp" # Change this to the path of your output FC.

spatialref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # Create the spatial reference object as WGS84. Can modify if desired.

if not arcpy.Exists(outfc): # Create the output feature class if needed. (if this is not an existing path, create it)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), 
os.path.basename(outfc), "POINT", None, None, None, spatialref)

csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n") # Register the dialect for native CSV syntax in Microsoft Excelself.
f = open(incsv, "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = "xls")

headers = reader.next() # Read the first line as the header names.

for header in headers[2:]: # Add fields for remaining columns if needed. Default is TEXT field.
    arcpy.AddField_management(outfc, header, "TEXT")

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@XY'] + headers[2:]) # Create 
InsertCursor.
count = 0
for row in reader:
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print "processing row {0}".format(count)
        Ycoord = row[0] # Make sure 'Lat' is in the 1st column.
        Xcoord = row[1] # Make sure 'Lon' is in the 2nd column.
        newrow = [(float(Xcoord), float(Ycoord))] + row[2:]
        cursor.insertRow(newrow) # Insert point in FC for each row in CSV.
        count += 1

del cursor
f.close()
```

Comment: Have a read of os.listdir() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm and os.path.splitext() https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/58/os.path.splitext to get the extension and file name before extension, from here use a loop for incsv in os.listdir(r'c:\folder\with\csv\files'): if os.path.splitext(incsv)[1].lower() == '.csv': outfc = os.path.join( YourOutputFolder, os.path.splitext(incsv)[0] + '.shp'), indent your code and it should all be good.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment:

```
import arcpy
import csv
import os
print "arcpy imported"

"""
# Author: John K. Tran
# Contact: jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu

Input CSV can look like:

Lat,Lon,First Name,Last Name
12.34,56.78,Joe,Smith
0.98,7.65,Jane,Doe
65.43,43.21,Bob,Sagat

Make sure 'Lat' and 'Lon' fields are the 1st and 2nd column in the CSV 
respectively.

"""


CSVfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Change this to the path of your CSV files.
SHPfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Change this to the path of your output FC.

spatialref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # Create the spatial reference object as WGS84. Can modify if desired.

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True # set overwrite, if the shapefile already exists it will be created

for incsv in os.listdir(CSVfolder): # loop through ALL files in the input folder
    if os.path.splitext(incsv)[1].lower() == '.csv': # check the file is a CSV file
        outfc = os.path.join(SHPfolder,os.path.splitext(incsv)[0] + '.shp')
        # create the new shapefile here
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(SHPfolder,os.path.basename(outfc), "POINT", None, None, None, spatialref)
        csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n") # Register the dialect for native CSV syntax in Microsoft Excelself.
        with open(os.path.join(CSVfolder,incsv), "r") as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = "xls")

          headers = reader.next() # Read the first line as the header names.

          for header in headers[2:]: # Add fields for remaining columns if needed. Default is TEXT field.
                  arcpy.AddField_management(outfc, header, "TEXT")
          # using a with block to create and manage the insert cursor.. does not work with arcpy.InsertCursor
          # ensures that the resources are properly released at the end.
          with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@XY'] + headers[2:]) as cursor:
              count = 0
              for row in reader:
                      if count % 1000 == 0:
                              print "processing row {0}".format(count)
                              Ycoord = row[0] # Make sure 'Lat' is in the 1st column.
                              Xcoord = row[1] # Make sure 'Lon' is in the 2nd column.
                              newrow = [(float(Xcoord), float(Ycoord))] + row[2:]
                              cursor.insertRow(newrow) # Insert point in FC for each row in CSV.
                              count += 1

        # del cursor # no longer needed with the with block.
        # f.close() # no longer needed with the with block.
```

I have changed the arguments to the *folder* the CSV files are in and the *folder* you want the shapefiles in. The shape name will be the same as the CSV name with the extension changed to `.shp`.

I am using [os.listdir()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) but [arcpy.ListFiles()](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000018000000) might work better as you can supply a wildcard (`*.csv`). Then using [os.path.splitext(filename)](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/58/os.path.splitext) will break the file name into a tuple of (name, extension), I use the 2nd element (index 1 as indexing is 0 based) converted to lower case to check the file is a CSV before progressing to the next line.

Comment: You could also use the glob stdlib to do all of that in one line.  `csv_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(csv_folder, '*.csv'))`

Comment: @gberard that's a good suggestion, there are indeed many ways to achieve this but as the original question was already importing os I would stick to the libs the user is currently using - the OP is a beginner I didn't want to confuse the topic by introducing more advanced libs.

Comment: Hi both, thank you for your suggestions. @MichaelStimson, I ran the code that you wrote and came up with the following error:  

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\skelley\Python\Scripts\FWDimport2.py", line 36, in <module>
    f = open(incsv, "r")
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'FWD_Halsey_WGS1984.csv'

    Failed to execute (FWDImport).

Comment: Note - I made one minor change, removed this piece (as it was for naming a single file and was no longer needed):

    + "\\" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) + ".shp"

Apologies for the formatting - I can't seem to get my comments to display the code properly. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Doh! you're right, there is no need for the extra 3rd argument. I should have noticed that; I'll fix it straight away. Comments (and chat) don't display code correctly, especially python where indentation is *vital*. Does the code work for you now?

Comment: Hi Michael - it's still throwing that error on line 36. I'm honestly not sure what it means - the csv file name there that the error references is the first file in the group that I'm trying to run the script on.

Comment: I see the problem, it's calling open() on the incsv which is a file name not a full path, so open can't find the file, I have changed this to a with block and full path using os.path.join(). Hopefully there are no more bugs.

Comment: Hi Michael - I tried that and it's throwing the same error. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you providing the arguments of *folder* the CSV files are in and *folder* you want your shapefiles to appear in?

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "U:\skelley\Python\Scripts\FWDimport2.py", line 36, in <module> f = open(incsv, "r") IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'FWD_Halsey_WGS1984.csv' Failed to execute (FWDImport)

Comment: Yes to both - inputs are both folders.

Comment: You haven't incorporated todays' edits to the code. Copy/paste from the line after csv.register_dialect

Answer (score 2):

You can use MakeXYEventLayer instead of insertcursor. No need to add fields etc.:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, basename

csvpath = r'C:\Test\Testmapp'
outshapefolder = r'C:\Test\Outputshapes'

files = [join(csvpath,f) for f in listdir(csvpath) if isfile(join(csvpath, f))]

for f in files:
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table=f, out_view='tempview')
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(table='tempview', in_x_field='Lat', in_y_field='Lon', 
                                     out_layer='tempevent', spatial_reference=4326)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='tempevent', out_feature_class=join(outshapefolder,basename(f).replace('.csv','.shp')))
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks a lot like my first attempt. I was thinking of going back to this approach - the only reason I used the approach in my original post was because I found it in a thread that discussed which method would import CSV data faster - the consensus was that the geoprocessing tools were slower. However, it might be worth trying both ways and comparing the speed myself. Appreciate the response!

Comment: In my experience the geoprocessing tools are faster than anything done solely in python. There is some overhead converting python objects to C objects and *a lot* more goes on in the background of python interpreting instructions whereas the geoprocessing tools are already compiled and linked and have almost no overhead. The problem I have with importing CSV files using this method is that the ArcGIS handling of CSV files, especially large ones, is dodgy at best. I suggest using MS Office (or similar) to import the CSV into a personal geodatabase table for reliability before using this method.

Comment: As a heads up for anyone attempting to use this script, in_x_field should be Longitude and in_y_field should be Latitude. Also be aware that it will create a schema.ini file in the csvpath folder which causes errors if attempting to rerun the script using the same input folder. You can add a line to check for and delete this file to fix the issue.